# How to specify what user I am using to git pull from terminal

Tags: git, command-line, pull

I'm trying to pull from a repo on GitHub but I'm having some problems.
I've already setup the SSH keys both in the account on Github and in my machine.
I'm using this command to set the url for the repo:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<repo>/<repo>.git
```

But when I do the

```
git pull
```

It gives me this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I think it has something to do with specify what user is trying to pull. How can I specify that using the command line?

Comment: Is the repo private? Do you have permission to see it?

Comment: Yes it is private and yes I have the permissions

Comment: When you say `and in my machine`, what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: The machine I'm using to pull from github

Comment: :-) What I mean is _what did you do to set it up in your computer_?

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't understand. I've generated the private key and the public key following the official documentation. I can pull and push using gitkraken, but not from the command line

Comment: right.... but the key can be placed anywhere.... and that does not mean that git will _guess_ that it has to use it. How can you make sure that git _is_ using it?

Comment: Well I'm not sure it is using it at this point.

Comment: My key was saved inside a file called "authorized_keys" inside the ~/.ssh folder

Comment: Ok... that's _not_ how to use a key so that git uses it to go against github. You _could_ run `ssh-add the-private-key`, provide password if it was setup with one... once that is successful, you might try going against github.